# lightweight webserver to integrate on client end

Tags: python, webserver

I need to create a python module that will be installed on end-user machines. One of the scripts in that module should be able to receive http POSTS (usually with some JSON formatted data in the body) and then pass on that data to an appropriate python script.  I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Open a listening server socket on port 80, wait for that http request to come in, parse it and then pass that data to another python script depending on the url that arrived.  This method will not require the end-user to install a webserver.  End user only has to install the python module.
2. Have a mini-webserver installed along with the python module. The webserver will do the same job as [a] via CGI without me requiring to write the CGI functionality.  But then the user will have to install the web-server (ie., the hassle of yet another install). Would like to avoid that if possible.

IF [b] is the easier option, **what is the smallest simplest webserver there is** (preferably one that can be packaged as part of the python module itself so that it does not have to be separately installed).  Must be opensource of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

batteries included
[Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)
[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)

Comment: Cool !  Thanks ... I see there is an extension for CGIhttpServer as well.